# setting path for download file

Tags: php, csv, download

I would like to set the path for all downloads downloaded to be in a specific file (targeted files are mostly excel's csv files), using php. Does anyone have any solution to this? I had tried file_put_contents but failed.

Appreciate all replies. Thank you.

Comment: Where is the code you tried ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell a browser that a file should be downloaded (i.e. that it is an attachment), and provide a default file name using the Content-Disposition HTTP response header.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv
```

e.g.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
readfile('/foo/bar/baz.csv');
```

You can't specify what directory the file should be saved to on the client system.